# loadXml returns undefined on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, toast, win-universal-app, xmldocument, windows-10

I'd like to create a custom toast, like Cortana uses, in my Windows 10 Universal App. Therefore I'm trying to pass a custom XML Snippet to the ToastNotification Class.

```
var xmlDocument = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();

var xml = "<toast><visual></visual></toast>";
var toastXml = xmlDocument.loadXml(xml);

// var toast = new notifications.ToastNotification(xmlDocument.loadXml(xml));
// var toastNotifier = notifications.ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier();
// toastNotifier.show(toast);
```

But sadly xmlDocument.load(xml) always returns undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to use the populated `XmlDocument` variable instead of using the return value of `loadXml`, something like :

```
xmlDocument.loadXml(xml);
var toast = new notifications.ToastNotification(xmlDocument);
```